# Python: Increase index in loop and call function

Tags: python, dictionary

I am learning Python. I have below code to ask user to enter few details. But when I am calling this function, it's not increasing `index` instead its changing the existing record.

Can i get some help here?

```
menuList = {}

def updateMenu():
    item = input('Item Name: ')
    price = int(input("Enter Price: "))
    key = 1
    menuList[key] = {'item':item,'price':price}  
    return menuList
```

Comment: you need to increment the key. `key+=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hard-coding the `key=1`, so the user input will always reference the values associated with key 1.
`menuList` is also a Global variable as defined by your first line of code. It's slightly confusing that you are naming a local variable with the same name. It may be better to do the following:

```py
menuList = {}

def updateMenu():
    global menuList
    key = len(menuList.keys()) + 1  # assumes no keys are ever deleted
    item = input('Item Name: ')
    price = int(input("Enter Price: "))
    menuList[key] = {'item':item,'price':price}
```

Now when you call `updateMenu` you do not need to set it equal to menuList

```py
updateMenu()
# answer the prompts
# menuList will get updated
```

Comment: Thanks Alec! I knew that this key needed to be updated but did not know how.

Answer (score 1):

Every time that you call `updateMenu` function, you use the same key `1` and overwrite your previous data! So your `menuList` will always have one key which is `1`.

You must define `key` as global variable and increase it every time you call the function.

Also you can use some other key for dictionary, for example you can use `item` if you think that it's unique.

Also i suggest using list and appending to it if you have no intention of using those integer keys in your `menuList` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `updateMenu()`, `key` is set to 1.

You need to change that to:

```
key+=1
```